# How Do You Form An Object Using Different Shapes in CSS?

Tags: css

I am currently experimenting on CSS shapes and I am making an icon that forms like a circle with a NECKTIE. I am combining 2 different triangles but it's really hard to form because I am really bad at imagining shapes and forms.

Here is my source code:

```css
.upper {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 12px solid transparent;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 22px solid #353332;
    transform: rotate(76deg);
    position: relative;
}
.upper::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 14px solid #EEE328;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 9px;
    left: -7px;
}

.lower {
 width: 0;
height: 0;
border-bottom: 27px solid #353332;
border-right: 17px solid transparent;
transform: rotate(-31deg);
margin-top: -17px;
margin-left: 14px;
 }

.lower::before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-bottom: 27px solid #EEE328;
border-right: 17px solid transparent;
transform: rotate(-31deg);
transform: rotate(0deg);
top: 5px;
bottom: 9px;
left: -7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="neck-tie">
     <div class="upper"></div>
     <div class="lower"></div>
</div>
```

I put everything in a container. The `.upper` class is the bigger triangle with 3 equal sides and the `.lower` class is the longer one. I added a `::before` in each of the classes since I wanted it to be bordered. 
My main div is rotated `19deg`. I'm not posting everything in here so that you can understand how my code works. I will just explain what's inside my files.

Comment: You are finding it difficult because CSS is not a graphic drawing program. To do such things, you should look into SVG or webGL. Doing such things with CSS is cute, in that it can be a fun experiment, but it resembles a hack and becomes very unwieldy.

Comment: Actually, I'm doing this for my students. I am currently teaching HTML and CSS to them and I wanted to create an object to present to them different css attributes for their learning. @Rob

Comment: I think you are doing them a disservice. But maybe not.

Comment: are you trying to get a diamond effect with 2 triangles?

Comment: I might be able to help you but I don't know what shape you are trying to achieve. Is there an image online you can point to?

Comment: yes. somehow, it will look like a necktie though @Jonny

Comment: yes hello, I have it here. it is in my previous question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD4vC.png @Bjorn.B

Comment: though It is not necessary that it would look exactly like that. I just wanted to combine shapes so it would look similar as that. @Bjorn.B

Comment: You mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/hykgavm4/2/

Comment: this one is close enough though, but maybe I'll consider this. I will just have to change the color of the other triangle to yellow. Thank you so much, @Bjorn.B

Comment: It's a lot easier to use canvas for complex shapes, if you think a small image takes too long to load. That's so small, I would use an image that you draw yourself with something like GIMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just playing around I came up with this it isn't anything like your code but I think I captured what you want. I used several divs with absolute positioning and rotated 3 divs one to give the appearance of the upper portion of the tie and 2 to give the appearance of the lower portion.

```css
.tieContainer{
width:100px;
height:250px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-50px;
top:10px;
overflow:hidden;
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.tieTopContainer{
width:100%;
height:60px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.tieTop{
width:60px;
height:160px; 
transform: rotate(45deg);
overflow:hidden;
background-color:yellow;
margin-left:-20px;
margin-top:15px;
border:5px black solid;
}

.tieBottomContainer{
width:100%;
height:134px; 
overflow:hidden;
}
.tieBottom{
width:70px;;
height:170px; 
background-color:yellow;
margin-left:16px;
 
}
.trimRight{
width:80px;
height:152px;
position:absolute;
transform: rotate(15deg);
background-color:#ffffff; 
border-left:6px black solid;
margin-left:67px;
margin-top:7px;
}
.trimLeft{
width:80px;
height:152px;
position:absolute;
transform: rotate(-15deg);
background-color:#ffffff; 
border-right:6px black solid;
margin-left:-52px;
margin-top:7px;
}
.knotCon{
width:40px;
height:30px;
overflow:hidden;
border-bottom:5px black solid;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-20px;
}
.knot{
width:60px;
height:160px; 
transform: rotate(45deg);
overflow:hidden;
background-color:yellow;
margin-left:-50px;
margin-top:9px;
border:5px black solid;
 }
```

```html
<div class="tieContainer">

<div class="tieTopContainer">
<div class="tieTop"></div>
</div>
<div class="tieBottomContainer">
<div class="trimRight"></div>
<div class="trimLeft"></div>
<div class="tieBottom"></div>
</div>
<div class="knotCon">
<div class="knot"></div>
</div>

</div>
```